# Microsoft Visual Studio Code license to use

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found that the Visual Studio Code FAQ answer says we can use vscode for personal of commercial use (see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_is-vs-code-free) with link to the product license: https://code.visualstudio.com/license that contains following:

> 1. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS
>
> a. General. You may use any number of copies of the software to develop and test your applications, including deployment within your internal network corporate network.
>
> b. Demo use. The uses permitted above include use of the software in demonstrating your applications.

Does item "b. Demo use." limits the item "a. General."? So is it allowed to use Visual Studio Code for DEMO purpose only, without right to develop commercial applications, provide service to create commercial code based on the Visual Studio Code IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not a lawyer**, but I'd say that 1b is specifically singling out using VSCode for demos as a use case that they permit, in addition to the above use cases. If I had to guess what motivated it, I'd assume:

- People doing commercial screencasts of demo libraries
- Those people who develop apps and publish a fast-forward of them coding it on youtube
- Generally anyone using the image (legal term, not executable) of vscode in a commercial way that could be construed as microsoft endorsing their product in any way.

I think they're including this clause because demoing your app to (potential) customers, clients, students, etc. isn't necessarily a development concern, so it's not covered by 1a.

Another thing that makes me think that it's a permissive clause rather than a restrictive one is that they're not using restrictive terms such as "exclusively" or "only". Compare the following:

> b. Demo use. The uses permitted above include use of the software in demonstrating your applications.

> b. Demo use. The uses permitted above include **ONLY** use of the software in demonstrating your applications.

The second one is obviously a modifier on "the uses permitted above" that restricts those uses, where the first one clarifies an intended use case.

### TLDR

It's probably fine, but if you're really worried, CYA by consulting your company's legal department.

Answer (score 0):

I requested Microsoft support to get the "official answer", I can't share it, because it's for internal company purpose, but, in general as I understood the Visual Studio Code available for free and I can use the VSCode for commercial software development